# TransactionScope in .NET

Tags: .net, transactionscope

Is the `TransactionScope` can be used only for Database/ADO.NET related methods?

Say, I have a Data Access Layer method which performs few activities:

- one activity includes a database update,
- another one is writing to a file,
- and the third one is creating a registry entry.

The method can be considered success only if all the three activities are successful, otherwise it is a failure, and all the preceding activities should be reverted back.

Does `TransactionScope` supports this? If not, what is the best way of handling such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe file operations take part in the transactions.  It depends on the OS, I think Vista and Win7 do, but older versions do not.  A quick search shows a few assemblies you can download to do this.  Search for .NET Transactional File Manager on codeplex.

Here is another good link that may work for you: http://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/using-the-net-transactionscope/